# How to update a MySQL row with a particular value?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying create a profile page for a web application I'm building, and I have the profile page built out, and it pulls their data out of the database fine. When I try to update the information is where I have trouble.

It should only update the row that matches the current logged in member's username.  This is what I have so far:

I pull the data from the form:

```
$phpro_email = filter_var($_POST['phpro_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phpro_fname = filter_var($_POST['phpro_fname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phpro_lname = filter_var($_POST['phpro_lname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I connect to the database:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And I try to update the correct row using `UPDATE` three columns in my table name which is `phpro_users` and I specify the row using `WHERE` phpro_username is equal to the value of the current logged in users.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE phpro_users SET phpro_fname = :phpro_fname, phpro_lname = :phpro_lname, phpro_email = :phpro_email WHERE phpro_username = :phpro_username");
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_username', $phpro_username);
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_fname', $phpro_fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_lname', $phpro_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_email', $phpro_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
```

When I click submit on the form with this script as it's action and it's `method=post` I just get a blank white screen. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_username', $phpro_username);
```

to

```
$stmt->bindParam(':phpro_username', $phpro_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

It may be defaulting to something strange, best to force it to a value.

Comment: I'm a man of my words ;) good show. That one was a head scratcher.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SQL to use proper `UPDATE` syntax

```
UPDATE phpro_users SET
    phpro_fname = :phpro_fname, 
    phpro_lname = :phpro_lname, 
    phpro_email = :phpro_email
WHERE phpro_username = :phpro_username
```

You also don't need to use `filter_var()` since you're using prepared statements

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect your suggestions, and I'm still having the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post more of your code then? It sounded like your SQL statement was failing but if more is happening we're going to need more details

Comment: The only other code is the HTML form itself?  That's all I've got in terms of PHP. Do you want me to post the form?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be your problem. Try doing `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` after your `execute()` and see if it shows anything

Comment: This is the result: Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )

Comment: And the SQL isn't updating the row?

Comment: No, the values are staying the same as they were before the SQL runs